# Plot in Wolfram Mathematica 10.3

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I've been working on my statistics homework, where I'm supposed to build a maximum likelihood function, and then plot it. But for some reason mathematica shows me a graph without a plot:

[image: mathematica shows me a graph without a plot]

Here is my script:

```
caseLike[[Phi], y] := ([Phi]^y)*((1 - [Phi])^(1 - y))

totalLike[[Phi], data] := !( *UnderoverscriptBox[([Product]), (i = 1), (5)]((caseLike[[Phi], data[i]])))

Length[totalLike[[Phi], data_List]]

totalLike[[Phi], {0, 1, 1, 0, 1,}] (1 - [Phi])^( 5 - {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, Null}1 - {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, Null}[ 2] - {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, Null}[3] - {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, Null}[ 4] - {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, Null}[5]) !(*SuperscriptBox[([Phi]), ({0, 1, 1, 0, 1, Null}[ 1] + {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, Null}[2] + {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, Null}[ 3] + {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, Null}[4] + {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, Null}[5])])

Plot[totalLike[[Phi], data], {data, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Terrific debugging trick for empty Plots in MMA. Try an experiment of replacing your Plot with Table[totalLike[phi,data],{data,0,1,.02}] or something similar and see if the table is filled with nice reasonable numbers or if there is anything else in that Table.

Comment: you need underscores for all the function args, eg. : `caseLike[phi_, y_]:=`  (Be sure to restart your kernel when fixing such things )